# Does $x_n$ posses a weak$^* -$ convergent sequence by banach-aluoghlo Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space with the dual $X^\ast$. Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a norm-bounded sequence in $X^\ast$, then can we claim that $x_n$ posses a weak$^\ast$-convergent subsequence by Banach-Alaoglu Theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if $X$ is separable, no in general. See [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem), e.g.

Beware that a compact space need not be sequentially compact. And IIRC, $X=\ell^\infty$ is an example where this happens for the dual ball.

Comment: Thanks. So in general we only can say  it contains a weak$^* -$ convergent subnet. Right ?

Comment: @Redshoes yes, a subnet is fine, that works in any compact space.